# White space after footer <div> in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am implementing simple zooming feature, Every thing working fine but 
I am getting a problem of white space after footer .

I tried by adding position to html and body elements but it not working.

How to reproduce:

```
1. Copy the below code to .html file.
2. Open in Google Chrome.
3. Press multiple times Zoom-out('+') button.
4. Goto end of page. You can find white space after footer also.
```

Please need help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0033)http://3dant.com/apps/graphpaper/ -->
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function dragStart(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.getAttribute('id'));
    ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ev.target, 0, 0);
    return true;
}
function dragEnter(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    return true;
}
function dragOver(ev) {
    return false;
}
function dragDrop(ev) {
    var src = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(src));
    ev.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}

// Zooming
var sclVal = 1;
var minZoom = 0.5;
var maxZoom = 1.5;

function ZoomIn(event) {
    if (sclVal > minZoom ) {
        sclVal = sclVal - 0.1;
        //console.log(sclVal);
        if (sclVal > minZoom && sclVal < maxZoom) {
            $("#section").css("-ms-transform", "scale(" + sclVal + ")");
            $("#section").css("-webkit-transform", "scale(" + sclVal + ")");
            $("#section").css("transform", "scale(" + sclVal + ")");
            var marBot =  -1*parseInt((1-sclVal)*$("#section").height()) + 'px';
            console.log(marBot);
            $("#section").css("margin-bottom", marBot);
        }
    }
};

function ZoomOut(event) {
    if (sclVal < maxZoom ) {
        sclVal = sclVal + 0.1;
        //console.log(sclVal);
        if (sclVal > minZoom && sclVal < maxZoom) {
            $("#section").css("-ms-transform", "scale(" + sclVal + ")");
            $("#section").css("-webkit-transform", "scale(" + sclVal + ")");
            $("#section").css("transform", "scale(" + sclVal + ")");
            var marBot =  -1*parseInt((1-sclVal)*$("#section").height()) + 'px';
            console.log(marBot);
            $("#section").css("margin-bottom", marBot);
        }
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#ZoomOut").click(function(event) {
        ZoomOut();

    });


    $("#ZoomIn").click(function(event) {
        ZoomIn();

    });


});
</script>
<style>
#graph_paper {
    border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
    height: 700px;
    width: 1340px;
}

#header {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

#nav {
    line-height: 30px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    height: 700px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
}

#section {
    width: 350px;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    transform-origin: top left;
}

#footer {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    left:10px;
}

#cellDiv2 {
    height: 500px;
    width: 350px;
    border: 1px #D3D3D3 solid;
}

td,table {
    border: 1px solid #a1a1a1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Id Card Print</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="nav">

            <table id="table1" draggable="true" ondragstart="return dragStart(event)">
                <tr>
                    <td>aaaaaaaaaa</td>
                    <td>bbbbbbbbbb</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>cccccccccc</td>
                    <td>dddddddddd</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        <input id="ZoomIn" type="button" value="-" />
        <input id="ZoomOut" type="button" value="+" />
    </div>
    <div id="section">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="cellDiv2" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)"
                        ondrop="return dragDrop(event)"
                        ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="cellDiv2" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)"
                        ondrop="return dragDrop(event)"
                        ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="cellDiv2" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)"
                        ondrop="return dragDrop(event)"
                        ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="cellDiv2" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)"
                        ondrop="return dragDrop(event)"
                        ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="cellDiv2" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)"
                        ondrop="return dragDrop(event)"
                        ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="cellDiv2" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)"
                        ondrop="return dragDrop(event)"
                        ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="cellDiv2" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)"
                        ondrop="return dragDrop(event)"
                        ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="cellDiv2" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)"
                        ondrop="return dragDrop(event)"
                        ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="cellDiv2" ondragenter="return dragEnter(event)"
                        ondrop="return dragDrop(event)"
                        ondragover="return dragOver(event)"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>

    <div id="footer">Copyright ..............</div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z16jc6wa/4/

Answer (score 2):

Need to make your `body` default margin values to `margin:0`

Add this to your style

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z16jc6wa/5/)**

Comment: Sorry, Still there is white space after footer.

Comment: Try `*{padding:0;margin:0}`

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has a user agent style on the body

```
body { 
   display: block;  
   margin: 8px;
}
```

override with this in your css file

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

***UPDATE****

seens to work fine

http://jsfiddle.net/upy1a7fs/1/

Comment: applied but no result, it happening in Chrome only

Answer (score 0):

Use style

```
BODY{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
```